# need explanations for this code in java. How does arraylist work in this code?

Tags: java, arraylist

Consider the following method:

```
public static void mystery2(ArrayList<Integer> list) {

    for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        if (i % 2 == 0) {

            list.add(list.get(i));

        } else {

            list.add(0, list.get(i));

        }

    }

    System.out.println(list);
}
```

list is

> [10, 20, 30]
>
> [8, 2, 9, 7, 4]
>
> [-1, 3, 28, 17, 9, 33]

and answer is

> [20, 10, 20, 30, 30, 20]
>
> [8, 7, 8, 2, 9, 7, 4, 4, 2, 8]
>
> [33, 28, 33, -1, 3, 28, 17, 9, 33, 17, -1, 33]

Can anyone explain it step by step?

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: This is totaly different question and code.

Comment: read the accepted answer **for comprehension**, same exact solution, it explains the difference between the `.add` methods

Answer (score 0):

`list.add(someNumber)` will insert the number at the end of the list, while `list.add(0 , someNumber)´ will insert the number at the start of the list. Note that the loop **doesn't** iterate over all elements of the intial list.